# How to find the distribution probability in user's chech-ins?

Tags: foursquare, checkin, power-law, recommendation-engine

I read a paper that mentioned the user's check-in behavior follow a power-law distribution. I want to know how to I can calculate a user's check-in behavior?

[image]

This is the figure of probability and they said:

> To obtain this measurement, we calculate the distances between all pairs of POIs that a user has checked in and plot
>   a histogram (actually probability density function) over the
>   distance of POIs checked in by the same user. As shown in
>   Figure 2, a significant percentage of POIs pairs checked in
>   by the same user appears to be within short distance, indicating a geographical clustering phenomenon in user check-in
>   activities.7